# Substring when a string contains, Linq syntax

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

in Linq i have somthing like

```
nodes.Select(td => td.InnerText.
                Replace("&amp;", "&").
                Substring(0, td.InnerText.IndexOf("+"))).
                ToArray();
```

some times td.InnerText contians a + sign and sometimes it doesn't and if it doesn't i get null reference exception.

how can i apply `Substring(0, td.InnerText.IndexOf("+")))` only if td.InnerText contains "+" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
td.InnerText.Replace("&amp;", "&").Substring(0, td.InnerText.IndexOf("+") > -1 ? td.InnerText.IndexOf("+") : 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using ternary operator. This might not work properly but will give you a hint.

```
nodes.Select(td => td.InnerText.Replace("&amp;", "&").Substring(0, 
    (td.InnerText.Contains("+")==true? td.InnerText.IndexOf("+"):string.Empty))).
                    ToArray();
```